# Spring batch thread safe

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to create spring batch which should be thread safe.
**problem statement **:
I tigger job 1 to insert data into database where my target table is employee
My 2nd job triggered immediately after job 1 where i want update data in the table where my taget table is the same.

Since job 1 is not completed and i am triggering job 2 immediately. Operation(insert/update) i want to perform against the respective file upload causing error.

Looking for your suggestion.

i tried stepscope and it is not helping.

what i tried:
@Bean(name = "xxx")
public Job xxxProcess(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step xxxProcessWrite) {
return jobBuilderFactory
.get("xxxProcess")
.flow(xxxReadProcessWrite)
.end()
.listener(new JobCompletionListener())
.build();
// @formatter:on
}

@Bean
public Step xxxReadProcessWrite(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, SynchronizedItemStreamReader multiResourceItemReader) {
// @formatter:off
return stepBuilderFactory
.get("xxxReadProcessWrite")
.<xxxDto, xxxDto>chunk(1)
.reader(multiResourceItemReader)
.writer(xxxItemWriter())
.faultTolerant()
.skipPolicy(new CustomSkipPolicy())
.build();
// @formatter:on
}

Comment: Before addressing the implementation of this requirement with Spring Batch, do you think that performing inserts and updates concurrently is correct? What about running a single job that does insertOrUpdate? If you still think you need two jobs, how would you do that without Spring Batch?

Comment: Insert and update concurrently fine if you are not updating the same record.
ya running 2 jobs is fine, if I am not using the spring batch will use jdbcTemplate to running insert and update queries

Comment: Are you running jobs in the same JVM? Because if you think you can insert and update data concurrently, then you can run two jobs in different JVMs which should remove the threading configuration (ie the need for step-scope) by design.